# How do I make a link sent by mail and made by random tokens access their own data in a PHP page

Tags: php, email

I have a token that I have created randomly in PHP. I created this token to be able to send it via mail to the intended user. After the link is made what I don't know is how I will make it so that the link accesses the intended data because the actual page does not exist since tokens are created randomly and a poll can be the same one but everyone has different answers. All the data needed is stored in a database.

table
**token**
*token* primary key
*idPoll* (fk)
email

table
**Poll**
*idPoll* primary key
title
question

table
**answer**
*idPoll* (fk)
*idAnswer* primary key
answer

What I want to do is make that token into a link to be able to read the data related to that token after accessing the link.

e.g.
token = randomTokenealjnlfa
link to access users own poll with their token.
www.myWebsite.com/polls/randomTokenealjnlfa

This is my php code for my mail

```
<?php

// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', ';
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Quick Poll';
$token = "nfjdsfEXAMPLEkajsdnlkaj";
$link = "www.example.com/polls/";
$linkToken = $link.$token;

// message
$message = $linkToken;

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: me <myMail@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myMailArchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: myMailCheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: You would have to store the tokens (and related data) in a database of some form.

Comment: They are all stored in a database

Comment: Then please improve the question with those details so that we can see the context and provide a useful answer.  Otherwise, it's just theoretical.

Comment: "All the data needed is stored in a database."

Comment: "Then please improve the question"

Answer (score 1):

You said you have token in database, so pseudocode is here:

In example.com/polls/token

```
$tokenString = $_GET['token'];
$tokenModel = FindTokenFromDatabase('token');
//All other code to generate token specific content
```

You probably want to link token to your user in your database.
Also note that /polls/token only works if you have correctly setup pretty links in your webserver, if you dont have it setup you should use:

example.com/polls?token=token

There is no universal code in here.

Comment: how would you do what? as I said there is no universal code, you need to get token from url with $_GET, then you will find token from database and then you will do token specific poll. It is not possible to write you all that code in here without knowing your application.